# Extract just one column of data from HTML table w/ Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, html-table, lxml

I'm attempting to extract some NBA stats for a little project I am doing, and I need to extract just a couple of the columns' (going up and down, vertically) data from an HTML table, like [this one here](http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2015/). I am only trying to get PTS for now, so how should I go about only pulling out that one column of data? I've figured out that it is the third to last element of each data-row, but I am not sure how I should go about parsing the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read the whole html table and then just select the column you need. Maybe you will lose something in speed but you will gain more in simplicity.

That is easy to do with pandas' read_html function:

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd

page1 = urllib2.urlopen(
    'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2015/').read()

#Select the correct table by some attributes, in this case id=pgl_basic.
#The read_html function returns a list of tables.
#In this case we select the first (and only) table with this id
stat_table = pd.io.html.read_html(page1,attrs={'id':'pgl_basic'})[0]

#Just select the column we needed. 
point_column = stat_table['PTS']

print point_column
```

If you are not familiar with pandas yet you can  read more from:
http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/10min.html

For example you might want to remove the header rows from the table or split the table to multiple tables.